# Sharing the HtmlHelper Class between a View and it's Partials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm have written a Custom Html Helper and and it can be called from any view like the following @Html.FootNoteNumberedLink.  The problem is that I have a fairly complex set of partial views nested within the view and this particular helper needs to keep track of the data that has been added via other partial views.  In other words, it is keeping a running tally of all the Footnotes for the entire view (that contains partial views).  The problem is that @Html seems to be instantiated at every partial view load. Meaning that my helper can not have a footnotes 1,2,3 from partial view 1 and continue on with the footnote 4, 5, 6 on partial view 2, instead the HtmlHelper is new on every partial view hence the data can not be appended.

The internal workings of the footnote are using ViewData to store the list of foot notes as such:    ViewData[ViewDataKey] as List

Any anyone explain why MVC is doing this or am I doing something wrong?

As usual thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlHelper is intented to be used as a simple markup generator class. Using it for keeping track of changes is probably not a good idea.

Instead, I would create a strongly typed viewmodel and populate it in the controller.
Then you can pass the viewmodel to your main view and just print it.

Your views should do nothing except painting whatever information the controller is passing.